# How do I increment a counter and disable a button in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, counter

I have a button I want to disable after incrementing my counter. This is the method I'm using to increment my counter:

```
void incrementAdCounter() async {
    setState(() {
      adCounter++;
      if (adCounter == 2 || adCounter > 2) {
        isAdButtonDisabled = true;
      }
      setAdCounter();
      print(adCounter);
    });
  }
```

Inside initState:

```
void initButtons() {
    isAdButtonDisabled = false;
    adCounter = 0
}
```

I have a button and I've called these methods on the onTap if the buttons:

```
void getCounters() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  adCounter = prefs.getInt('adCounter');
  isAdButtonDisabled = prefs.getBool('isAdButtonDisabled');
}
setAdCounter() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('adCounter', adCounter);
    prefs.setBool('isAdButtonDisabled', isAdButtonDisabled);
  }
```

When I call this method it shows me the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.
E/flutter (13166): Receiver: null
```

Comment: You may be forgot to initialize `adCounter` with some value.

Comment: No I initialised it but it still isn't working.

Comment: Can you add full code?

Comment: this is what I've declared in the initState:
void initButtons() {
    isAdButtonDisabled = false;
    adCounter = 0
}

Comment: I think this is `null` : `adCounter = prefs.getInt('adCounter');`

Comment: Why not set breakpoints at all adCounter locations and see when they are null?

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but my answer, which you marked as correct, seemed to have solved it. What made you change your mind to mark another answer as correct? @SimranAswani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
void getCounters() async { 
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  adCounter = prefs.getInt('adCounter') ?? 0;
  isAdButtonDisabled = prefs.getBool('isAdButtonDisabled'); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**int adCounter=0;**  (initialize value first whatever you want)

```
void incrementAdCounter() async {
    setState(() {
      adCounter++;
      if (adCounter == 2 || adCounter > 2) {
        isAdButtonDisabled = true;
      }
      setAdCounter();
      print(adCounter);
    });
  }
```

Comment: I have initialised it. But its still showing me the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This modification of your original code will do exactly what you are asking for:

```
int adCounter = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(adCounter.toString()),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: adCounter >= 2 ? null : incrementAdCounter,
          child: Text('Increment'),
        ),
      ],
    )
  );
}

void incrementAdCounter() {
  setState(() {
    adCounter++;
  });
}
```

The rest of your code doesn't need modification with the exception of the fact that you don't need to save into SharedPreferences if your button is disabled. You can just validate it against the value.